# 'Multiple declarations of' error when pattern matching with wildcard

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching, wildcard

For learning purposes I am trying to write my own implementation of the `zipWith` function. However, I am hitting an issue with pattern matching on edge cases with `_`. First I will describe the good case, then the bad case. Hopefully someone will be able to explain why they behave differently. Thanks

If I write the `zipWith` function as follows, it works (Note the order of the edge cases matching empty list on lines 2 & 3):-

```
zipWith' :: (a -> b -> c) -> [a] -> [b] -> [c]
zipwith' _ [] _ = []
zipWith' _ _ [] = []
zipWith' f (x:xs) (y:ys) = f x y : zipWith' f xs ys
```

Compiling in GHCI:-

```
ghci> :l ZipWith.hs 
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( ZipWith.hs, interpreted )
```

Ok, the above is fine, yet if I swap the pattern matching for the edge cases around GHCI throws 'Multiple declarations of' error for lines 2 and 4.

```
zipWith' :: (a -> b -> c) -> [a] -> [b] -> [c]
zipWith' _ _ [] = []
zipwith' _ [] _ = []
zipWith' f (x:xs) (y:ys) = f x y : zipWith' f xs ys
```

Compiling in GHCI:-

```
ZipWith.hs:4:0:
    Multiple declarations of `Main.zipWith''
    Declared at: ZipWith.hs:2:0
                 ZipWith.hs:4:0
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

I'm stumped...

1. Looking at the patterns on lines 2 and 4 they seem mutually exclusive but i'm obviously missing something fundamental here
2. Why would switching the patterns on lines 2 and 3 cause the compilation error to go away.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The error message isn't complaining about overlapping patterns (your patterns do overlap in the case of two empty lists, but that's neither the problem, nor a problem), but multiple definitions of the `zipWith` function.

The reason for that is that in your second case you have one definition of `zipWith` followed by an unrelated definition of `zipwith` (note the lower case `w`), followed by a new, conflicting definition of `zipWith`. In other words it's a simple typo. (Did take me a while to see though - quite a sneaky typo)

Comment: Oh man that typo is so embarrassing on my part, thanks for spotting it and also explaining about my incorrect interpretation of the error.

Comment: +1 for both Q and A. Someone will surely Google this and want to see this answer.

Comment: They should really add something like "possibly  typo" to the error-message.